# Equation is floating in two columns and in equation array package

Tags: math-mode, equations, eqnarray

I'm sorry for such a basic question, however, I'm asking because I'm quite close to the deadline. So, my equations are floating on 2nd column based on the below MWE, I was trying to compress it somehow to manage them in a single column.  Kindly help me to fix it Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}      
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts           
\usepackage[ruled,longend,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetArgSty{textup}
\SetKwBlock{Loop}{Loop}{end}
\usepackage{array}\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
w_{t}^{j,buy} = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
w_{t}^{j,sel}u_{t}^{DS}+J_{t}^{by}(1-u_{t}^{DS}) &  \text{\emph{if} $0\leq u_{t}^{DS}\leq 1$}  \\
v_{t}^{sel} &  \text{\emph{otherwise}} 
\end{array} \right.
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{equation}
h_{t}^{j,by}=H_{t}^{j,sel} \Big( g_{t}^{M,L}-(g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s})\Big)\; if\; g_{t}^{M,L}>g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}\label{Eq9}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h_{t}^{j,sell}=H_{t}^{j,buy} \Big((g_{n,rr}^{j}+E_{t}^{h,y})-E_{y}^{M,L}\Big)\;\; if\; g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}>g_{t}^{M,L}\label{Eq10}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `cases` for the first equation and you can exploit `multilined` for the other two (requires `mathtools`).

In the first equation I used a small trick: the spaces around binary operation symbols and relations are half their usual value.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for context

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts           

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{equation}
\medmuskip=0.5\medmuskip
\thickmuskip=0.5\thickmuskip
w_{t}^{j,\mathrm{buy}} = 
\begin{cases}
w_{t}^{j,\mathrm{sell}}u_{t}^{DS}+J_{t}^{\mathrm{buy}}(1-u_{t}^{DS}) &
  \text{if $0\leq u_{t}^{DS}\leq 1$}  \\
v_{t}^{\mathrm{sell}} &
  \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{equation}\label{Eq9}
\begin{multlined}
h_{t}^{j,\mathrm{buy}}=H_{t}^{j,\mathrm{sell}} 
  \bigl(g_{t}^{M,L}-(g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s})\bigr)
\\
\text{if $g_{t}^{M,L}>g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}$}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3][1-3]
\begin{equation}\label{Eq10}
\begin{multlined}
h_{t}^{j,\mathrm{sell}}=H_{t}^{j,\mathrm{buy}}
  \bigl((g_{n,rr}^{j}+E_{t}^{h,y})-E_{y}^{M,L}\bigr)
\\
\text{if $g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}>g_{t}^{M,L}$}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that “buy” and “sell” should be upright. I also changed `\Big` to `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but one problem is still there, I can't use the buy and sell with \mathrm, it has to be in the math environment without any change, and I'm struggling with this way of doing :( :(

Comment: @Shane Well, remove `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this. I've assumed that `by` and `sel` are typos, and should in fact be `buy` and `sell`. Using `\text` to get proper spacing saves a few points and eliminates the overfull hboxes. Also, where an amsmath environment exists (`cases` here) it's usually better than constructing your own. Finally, never use `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
w_{t}^{j,\text{buy}} =
\begin{cases}
w_{t}^{j,\text{sell}}u_{t}^{DS}+J_{t}^{\text{buy}}(1-u_{t}^{DS}) &  \text{\emph{if} } 0\leq u_{t}^{DS}\leq\
 1  \\
v_{t}^{\text{sell}} &  \text{\emph{otherwise}}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
h_{t}^{j,\text{buy}}=H_{t}^{j,\text{sell}} \Big( g_{t}^{M,L}-(g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s})\Big)
 \text{ if } g_{t}^{M,L}>g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}\label{Eq9}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h_{t}^{j,\text{sell}}=H_{t}^{j,\text{buy}} \Big((g_{n,rr}^{j}+E_{t}^{h,y})-E_{y}^{M,L}\Big) \text{ if }
    g_{n,rr}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}>g_{t}^{M,L}\label{Eq10}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Thanks yes cases worked, but for equations, the problems still persist, I can't change buy and sell as text because in all my documents they have been used in a math environment so any other idea??

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[9pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
w_{t}^{j,\mathrm{buy}} =\begin{cases}
 w_{t}^{j,\mathrm{sel}}u_{t}^{DS}+J_{t}^{by}(1-u_{t}^{DS}) &  \text{ if } 0\leq u_{t}^{DS}\leq 1  \\
v_{t}^{\mathrm{sel}}&  \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
h_{t}^{j,\mathrm{by}}=H_{t}^{j,\mathrm{sel}} \Big( g_{t}^{M,L}-(g_{n,\mathrm{rr}}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s})\Big) \intertext{ if } g_{t}^{M,L}>g_{n,\mathrm{rr}}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}\label{Eq9}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
h_{t}^{j,\mathrm{sell}}=H_{t}^{j,\mathrm{buy}} \Big((g_{n,\mathrm{rr}}^{j}+E_{t}^{h,y})-E_{y}^{M,L}\Big) \intertext{ if } g_{n,\mathrm{rr}}^{j}+g_{t}^{j,s}>g_{t}^{M,L}\label{Eq10}
\end{align}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano, the cases worked but align does not work, before the equation number was going into another column now with "align" the texts are overflowing.

Comment: @Shane In the meantime, I apologize to you. Unfortunately as all the users know in TeX.SE. I'm not good in English language and I didn't understand what I was asking. Sorry.